# ¡Feliz año nuevo 2022!

Tags: discusión

*Muchas gracias a [@Excorpion](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131662/excorpion) por la traducción.*

---

#### Año en números

| Stack Overflow en Español | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Preguntas | 53.971 | 48.504 |
| Respuestas | 41.399 | 33.338 |
| Nuevos Usuarios | 50.045 | 50.628 |

<sup>*Estos números son absolutos, incluidas las publicaciones eliminadas.</sup>

#### Pensamientos sobre el futuro

Este año [Stack Overflow se convirtió en parte de Prosus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/). Después de la finalización de los procesos legales, comenzamos a contratar aún más activamente. Hoy en día, el equipo de Community Management está formado por 13 personas y lo más probable es que [más personas se unirán al equipo](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3726372/staff-community-manager-collectives).
Se están llevando a cabo cambios similares con el equipo de Plataforma pública (el equipo que desarrolla el software para el sitio). Creo que esto nos permitirá implementar muchas iniciativas útiles de las que hemos hablado mucho anteriormente y crear aún más herramientas para moderar la comunidad y el contenido.

¡Espero el próximo año con mucho optimismo! =)

#### ¡Felicitémonos unos a otros!

¡Terminemos este año y comencemos el próximo con algo positivo! ¡Únase a nuestras felicitaciones! Compartan las experiencias comunitarias positivas más agradables que recuerde. Si el año pasado algunos usuarios le hicieron algo bueno a usted o a la comunidad, por favor compártanlo en la respuesta a esta pregunta. Estoy seguro de que los demás usuarios estarán encantados de saber de ti.

¡Espero que 2022 nos traiga felicidad a todos y cada uno de nosotros!

Comment: StackExchange fue vendido en US$1.800 millones. Sus ingresos operacionales son ~US$70 millones al año. Creo que hay dinero suficiente para contratar a alguien en lugar de pedir que trabajemos gratis.

Comment: El CM de la comunidad deberia hacerlo en este caso... no me la creo que este tipo de informacion no se le haya enviado primero...

Comment: Deberían dar al menos 1 centavos dólar por cada voto positivo recibido

Comment: I vote you negative because I do not agree that someone from the staff / employee / moderator ask us to translate one of their news related to their work.  te voto negativo por que no estoy de acuerdo en que alguien del staff/empleado/moderador nos pidan que traduscamos una se sus noticias relacionada a su trabajo.

Comment: **¡Feliz año 2022 para todos los miembros de la comunidad, staff y sus familias!**; siento mucho que algunos tuvimos momentos no tan agradables relacionados con la pandemia, ¡pero deseo mejores y más felices momentos en la vida de cada uno de nosotros!  ✌️

Comment: Is the association of questions SO -> SOes working? http://es.rudevs.ru did not work upon login.

Comment: Hi @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'! It works (though there was an error which I've just fixed) but I still need to do manual sync of the associations. Please let me know if I need to update them.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky great, thanks! I have been adding the comment to several posts over the time, I am not sure if you have triggered it lately (maybe there could be a display in http://es.rudevs.ru indicating the last import date?).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Nice idea! Where do you think it should be displayed? Probably in the footer?

Comment: That could work well...

Answer (score 16):

## Gracias

Mi tiempo es Stack Overflow es bastante corto, me registré hace poco más de un año pero en realidad empecé a responder y ayudar a los demás unos meses después. Durante este tiempo he conocido a usuari@s bastante amigables, donde quiero hacer mención especial a [@Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe) y [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) que siempre me apoyaron y guiaron de muchas formas. No soy ningún experto en python y llegué aquí sin saber nada de este, pero aún así quería ayudar a los demás y ser parte de la comunidad de Stack Overflow. Cuando iniciaba vi algunas respuestas de [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) y ello me motivó a escribir respuestas tan buenas como las que el hace y creo que lo estoy logrando.

Me gusta demasiado el [Chat de SO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) ya que puedes interactuar con otros y aprender bastante de ellos. No todo es programación en el chat, también se habla de comida, animales, IA, opiniones sobre algunas preguntas/respuestas y a veces hay unas pequeñas "discusiones" (aunque niegan que lo son). Creo que con todas las personas con las que he hablado en el chat me han ayudado en algo, ya sea [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) guiándome en *"mi entrenamiento para ser mod"*, [@Dante S.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/158880/dante-s) explicándome algunos conceptos, [@abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) y [@Candid Moe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/180118/candid-moe) ayudándome en algunas tareas escolares XD, [@Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764/patricio-moracho) ayudándome en temas de investigación y estadística, [@Alfabravo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6798/alfabravo) mi salvador cuando estuve con Linux, [@Mauricio Contreras](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112837/mauricio-contreras) ayudándome con JS y Node, El [*TODO PODEROSO*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/46896/arcanis-the-omnipotent) que se para cambiando de nombre, [@g3rv4](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/11272/g3rv4) indicando que "Stack Overflow" **son 2 palabras** y no una, [@Excorpion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/131662/excorpion) al que le gané en ajedrez, [@padaleiana](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/156327/padaleiana) que siempre te observa O_o, [@Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma) con su icónica frase *"Asco de [dia de la semana]"*, etc.

Gracias a Stack Overflow he aprendido mucho y considero que es un buen lugar para ampliar tus conocimientos, ya que al responder aprenderás algo nuevo, tendrás que investigar y sustentar varias cosas, puedes leer respuestas/preguntas de muchos usuarios y entender cosas que no entendías. Creo que esto fue exactamente lo que necesitaba, un lugar donde pueda poner aprueba mis conocimientos, compartirlos, ayudar a otros y aprender de muchos otros.

No quiero extender más esta publicación así que culmino deseándoles a todos un **Feliz año nuevo a todos**, espero que continúen haciendo lo que hacen, que es compartir conocimiento para ayudar a otros :D.

Comment: Padaleiana* ;) ¡Feliz año nuevo! <3

Answer (score 6):

//Traducción//

Agradeceré la traducción de esta pregunta.

---

#### Año en números

| Stack Overflow en Español | 2020 | 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Preguntas | 53.971 | 48.504 |
| Respuestas | 41.399 | 33.338 |
| Nuevos Usuarios | 50.045 | 50.628 |

<sup>*Estos números son absolutos, incluidas las publicaciones eliminadas.</sup>

#### Pensamientos sobre el futuro

Este año [Stack Overflow se convirtió en parte de Prosus](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/). Después de la finalización de los procesos legales, comenzamos a contratar aún más activamente. Hoy en día, el equipo de Community Management está formado por 13 personas y lo más probable es que [más personas se unirán al equipo](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3726372/staff-community-manager-collectives).
Se están llevando a cabo cambios similares con el equipo de Plataforma pública (el equipo que desarrolla el software para el sitio). Creo que esto nos permitirá implementar muchas iniciativas útiles de las que hemos hablado mucho anteriormente y crear aún más herramientas para moderar la comunidad y el contenido.

¡Espero el próximo año con mucho optimismo! =)

#### ¡Felicitémonos unos a otros!

¡Terminemos este año y comencemos el próximo con algo positivo! ¡Únase a nuestras felicitaciones! Compartan las experiencias comunitarias positivas más agradables que recuerde. Si el año pasado algunos usuarios le hicieron algo bueno a usted o a la comunidad, por favor compártanlo en la respuesta a esta pregunta. Estoy seguro de que los demás usuarios estarán encantados de saber de ti.

¡Espero que 2022 nos traiga felicidad a todos y cada uno de nosotros!

Comment: FELICIDADES A TODOS LOS MIEMBROS DE LA COMUNIDAD. FELIZ 2022!!!

Comment: I vote you negative because I do not agree that someone from the staff / employee / moderator ask us to translate one of their news related to their work.  te voto negativo por que no estoy de acuerdo en que alguien del staff/empleado/moderador nos pidan que traduscamos una se sus noticias relacionada a su trabajo.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent en ese caso vota al que lo pide, no al traductor voluntario ;)

Comment: Hacer cosas de manera voluntaria no es apoyar la sinvergüenzura. Si el tipo es Ruso y solo habla español e inglés, no creo que esperes que traduzca al perfecto español... no veo que tiene de malo el solicitar ayuda, para eso está StackOverflow Meta.